# Running Tomcat with PostgreSql using Dockerfile

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, docker, dockerfile

I want to run a Tomcat with PostgreSql database within the same Dockerfile.

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:8-jre7

MAINTAINER "Sonam <mymail@gmail.com>"

RUN apt-get -y update

Add simplewebapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade

FROM postgres
```

When I run the docker image, I can't access the Tomcat like I could if I comment out the postgres.  How do I get Postgres running and Tomcat too?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only take one image as your base, just the same as you can only have one OS installed.

If you need to have two applications installed, then you need to build your own container - either starting from one and running the sequence of commands in the Dockerfile you need to install the other app, or just start from a base OS image, and install both.

Alternatively - why do you need them in the same container? Something like `--link` might do what you want, more effectively. Just run two containers, and link them.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand more now.  I have read the documentation and I am still a puzzled at where or how things fit.  I want to install a base OS image with Ubuntu and with Tomcat (with openjdk7).  The following is what I have so far:    FROM ubuntu:14.04
# Update Ubuntu

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install openjdk8
~

Comment: Yeah, pretty much that. How would you install these things on your host? Do that in your Dockerfile.